# Setting ID to Item in Spinner

Tags: java, android, json, android-spinner

I want set zone_id to item in spinner along with zone name which is coming from json

```
[{"zone_id":1,"zone_name":"North"},{"zone_id":2,"zone_name":"West"},{"zone_id":3,"zone_name":"South"},{"zone_id":4,"zone_name":"East"}]
```

This I have created a custom class

```
public class StringWithTag{
        public Object itemId;
        public String itemName;

        public StringWithTag(Object itemId,String itemName){
            this.itemId = itemId;
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }
    }
```

And adding items to list like this

```
instituteArrayList.add(new StringWithTag(itemId,itemName));
```

But the problem here is in the dropdown I get references of the object

I want the zones to be displayed in the spinner and when I click on any Zone respective ID should get fetch.

Comment: make it string can't you!!

Comment: Sorry didnt get you

Comment: see below solution what i was trying to explain

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to override `toString()` on your custom object. The object references come from the default `toString()` method defined by `Object`

```
public class StringWithTag{
    public Object itemId;
    public String itemName;

    public StringWithTag(Object itemId,String itemName){
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    @Override
    public void toString() {
        return this.itemName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Setters and Getters for Your Class

```
 public class StringWithTag {
        public String itemId;
        public String itemName;

        public StringWithTag(String itemId,String itemName){
            this.itemId = itemId;
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }

        public String getItemId() {
            return itemId;
        }

        public void setItemId(String itemId) {
            this.itemId = itemId;
        }

        public String getItemName() {
            return itemName;
        }

        public void setItemName(String itemName) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }
    }
```

and Apply Listener on Your Spinner

```
spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()      
      {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            int id = instituteArrayList.get(position)getItemId();
            }
        });
```

Comment: The stated problem is how the data is showing in the spinner, for that you don't need getters and setter but `toString()`